# In lodash.js, will it cache the result for `.value()` method?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, underscore.js, lazy-evaluation, lodash

For example, I have codes (coffeescript) like this:

```
sortedLatLng = _(w)
    .sortBy (x) -> x.time
    .map (x) -> [x.longitude,x.latitude]
    .uniq((x)-> x[0].toFixed(3) + "," + x[1].toFixed(3))   # keep three decimal to merge nearby points
console.log(sortedLatLng.value())
myFunction1(sortedLatLng.value())
myFunction2(sortedLatLng.value())
console.log(sortedLatLng.reverse().value())
```

This may be chained by other lodash method later. Meanwhile, its value may be necessary to be extracted. I was justing wonder whether it will cache the result. I didn't find how it is implemented in its documentation..

Will it be calculated once or twice for:

```
myFunction1(sortedLatLng.value())
myFunction2(sortedLatLng.value())
```

Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: You could figure this out easily by doing a strict comparison of two calls to `.value()`.

Comment: I have had issues three times now using the `lodash` library.  I am getting unexpected results, and I am also wondering if `lodash` is doing something with caching that I am not expecting.  For me, all results in my testing seem to indicate that `lodash` resulting objects persist/cache somehow, in a way that is inconvenient for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a lodash wrapper, the wrapped value is stored within the wrapper. For example:

```
var wrapper = _([ 1, 2, 3 ]);
```

Here, `[ 1, 2, 3 ]` is stored in `wrapper`, and any chained operations added to the wrapper are passed this value. Chained operations are *stored*, not executed. For example:

```
var wrapper = _([ 1, 2, 3 ]).map(function(item) {
    console.log('mapping');
    return item;
});
```

This code creates a wrapper with a `map()` operation, but doesn't execute it. Instead, it stores the chained operations so that when `value()` is called, it can execute them:

```
var wrapper = _([ 1, 2, 3 ]).map(function(item) {
    console.log('mapping');
    return item;
});

wrapper.value()
// mapping
// ...
```

Calling `value()` again on this wrapper will simply repeat the same operations on the wrapped value - results aren't cached.